# Get unique data from database closest to selected date

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get the data closest to a specific date either in the past or the future whichever is closer to the date. But I also need it to be `distinct` by `type`. For example:

```
id |type |data | date                
 1 |0    |1904 |2018-08-19 00:14:32
 2 |0    |1904 |2018-08-19 00:24:47
 3 |0    |1904 |2018-08-19 05:02:30
 4 |0    |1904 |2018-08-22 00:05:58
 5 |0    |1904 |2018-08-22 00:08:34
 6 |4    |1903 |2018-08-19 00:14:31
 7 |6    |1926 |2018-08-19 00:14:32
 8 |6    |1926 |2018-08-19 04:44:10
 9 |6    |1926 |2018-08-19 04:52:58
10 |6    |1926 |2018-08-19 04:59:23
11 |6    |1926 |2018-08-22 00:05:58
12 |6    |1926 |2018-08-22 00:07:52
13 |6    |1926 |2018-08-22 00:08:34
14 |7    |1564 |2018-08-19 00:14:32
15 |8    |1900 |2018-08-19 00:14:32
```

If I specify the datetime: `2018-08-19 00:00:00`. I should get the following results:

```
id | type
 1 | 0    
 6 | 4
 7 | 6
14 | 7
15 | 8
```

Or if I specify the datetime: `2018-09-03 00:00:00`. I expect:

```
id | type
 5 | 0    
 6 | 4
13 | 6
14 | 7
15 | 8
```

Or lastly: `2018-08-22 00:05:58`.

```
id | type
 4 | 0    
 6 | 4
11 | 6
14 | 7
15 | 8
```

I've tried a few queries that didn't really make sense... Like:

```
SELECT *
FROM history 
WHERE (ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, date, "2018-08-19 00:08:34")) < 4) AND user_id = 1299
GROUP BY type
ORDER BY date
```

Anyway, is this possible with a MySQL query alone? Do I need to use some application logic to pull this off? How do I query this?

[SQL fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/imzrsNZBFbw3DgbchjBdkZ/3)

Comment: @HABO I didn't tag it with `tsql`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This employs a standard query pattern for finding the row with the extreme value for each type. In this case, *extreme* means *closest to a target value.*

First, you need an aggregate subquery to get the extreme value: the minimum delta time between rows of each type and your target date. (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b51a7a/26/1)

```
      SET @target := '2018-08-20 00:00:00';
      SELECT type, MIN(ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, date, @target))) delta
        FROM history
       GROUP BY type
```

Then you join that to your original table, using the `ON` clause to match both type and delta time. Putting it all together (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b51a7a/27/1)

```
SET @target := '2018-08-20 00:00:00';
SELECT history.*
  FROM history
  JOIN (
          SELECT type, MIN(ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, date, @target))) delta
            FROM history
           GROUP BY type
      ) delta ON history.type=delta.type 
              AND ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, date, @target)) = delta
```

**Edit** it's easier to get only the nearest future or nearest past item to a date.  The subquery (for nearest past) is

```
         SELECT type, MAX(date) date
           FROM history
         WHERE date <= @target
         GROUP BY date
```

Then the overall query is

```
  SELECT history.*
    FROM history
    JOIN (
             SELECT type, MAX(date) date
               FROM history
             WHERE date <= @target
             GROUP BY date
         ) m ON history.type = m.type AND history.date = m.date
```

Comment: If I need to add additional filtering. Can I do it like this: `SELECT history.*
  FROM history
  JOIN (
          SELECT type, MIN(ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, date, @target))) delta
            FROM history
   WHERE user_id = 1299
           GROUP BY type
      ) delta ON history.type=delta.type 
              AND ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, date, @target)) = delta
     WHERE user_id = 1299`

Comment: Is it also possible to only get the closest future or past? not both.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an inner join on subquery for min diff

```
select 
    h.id, h.type 
from 
    history  
inner join  
    (select
         type, min(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, date, '2012-06-06 15:20:18')) min_diff 
     from  
         history
     where
         (abs(TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, date, "2018-08-19 00:08:34")) < 4) 
         and user_id = 1299
     group by  
         type) t on t.type = h.type 
                 and TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, h.date, '2012-06-06 15:20:18') = t.min_diff
```

Comment: It's not giving me the correct results. It seems to be providing only the latest data.

Answer (score 0):

You could easily do this  imitating `row_number()` function from other RDBMS ordering by `abs(timestampdiff(second, date, @dt))`:

```
select @rn := 0, @dt := cast('2018-08-19 04:52:00' as datetime);
select id, type from (
    select id,
           type,
           data,
           date,
           @rn := @rn + 1 rn
    from history
    order by abs(timestampdiff(second, date, @dt))
) a where rn = 1;
```

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/imzrsNZBFbw3DgbchjBdkZ/2)

Answer (score 0):

this should do the trick.

```
create table test2 as
select c.id,c.type from(
select a.*,b.min
from test as a
left join
(select id, min(abs(date-"2018-09-01 00:00:00"dt)) as min from test
group by type ) as b
on a.id = b.id
) as c
where min = abs(date-"2018-09-01 00:00:00"dt)
order by id;
```

we left join on id back to the original table the min abs datediff then we select the desired records.